# XML return all node name contain a substring

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Since I am new to XPath/XQuery, and trying to query a huge xml file data, so I thought, maybe somebody can help me with this issue.

I have a xml data that looks like:

```
<financial_statement>
  <revenue>123</revenue>
  <interestRevenue>234</interestRevenue>
  <salaries>12<salaries>
  <transactionRevenue>345</transactionRevenue>
  <revenueOtherServices>109</revenueOtherServices>
  <sales>783</sales>
  <costs>746</costs>
  .....
</financial_statement>
```

I would like to query this xml data and return only the nodes that contains the string "revenue" in their names. So the output should look like:

```
<revenue>
  <revenue>123</revenue>
  <interestRevenue>234</interestRevenue>
  <transactionRevenue>345</transactionRevenue>
  <revenueOtherServices>109</revenueOtherServices>
</revenue>
```

Actually I am not using a programming language. I have an XML database runs locally on [eXist](http://exist-db.org/) which consists an build-in XQuery engine. Therefore, I am looking for XPath/XQuery code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XQuery solution could look like the following. Return an outermost element `revenue`, and look for all elements whose name contains "revenue", either lowercase or uppercase, that's what the `translate()` function does.

Here, the input document is assigned to a variable `$x`, but you could also use the `doc()` function or any other means to retrieve XML data offered by eXist.

**XQuery**

```
let $x := <financial_statement><revenue>123</revenue><interestRevenue>234</interestRevenue><salaries>12</salaries><transactionRevenue>345</transactionRevenue><revenueOtherServices>109</revenueOtherServices><sales>783</sales><costs>746</costs></financial_statement>

return <revenue>{$x//*[contains(translate(name(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'revenue')]}</revenue>
```

Using `translate()` guarantees portability to XPath 1.0, but since XQuery uses XPath 2.0, you could also use `lower-case()` or `upper-case()` to mimic a case-insensitive `contains()` function.

**XML Output**

```
<revenue>
   <revenue>123</revenue>
   <interestRevenue>234</interestRevenue>
   <transactionRevenue>345</transactionRevenue>
   <revenueOtherServices>109</revenueOtherServices>
</revenue>
```

---

In case you really asked for an XSLT solution, the following transform does what you want. Since both XQuery and XSLT make use of XPath, the approach is almost the same.

**XML Input**

```
<financial_statement>
  <revenue>123</revenue>
  <interestRevenue>234</interestRevenue>
  <salaries>12</salaries>
  <transactionRevenue>345</transactionRevenue>
  <revenueOtherServices>109</revenueOtherServices>
  <sales>783</sales>
  <costs>746</costs>
</financial_statement>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <revenue>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </revenue>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(translate(name(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'revenue')]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<revenue>
   <revenue>123</revenue>
   <interestRevenue>234</interestRevenue>
   <transactionRevenue>345</transactionRevenue>
   <revenueOtherServices>109</revenueOtherServices>
</revenue>
```

---

> Actually I am not using a programming language.

Well, you know, XQuery *is* a programming language. In my opinion, that is.

Comment: Actually I just asked about XQuery, I just need to search a collection of a huge XML fikes. Thank you very much. I just tried it, and it worked like a charm :) Vielen Dank ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `name` function.  Here's an XSLT 1.0 solution.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="name (.)"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$n}">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="revenue">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="financial_statement"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="financial_statement">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:variable name="n" select="name (.)"/>
      <xsl:if test="contains ($n, &quot;revenue&quot;) or contains ($n, &quot;Revenue&quot;)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the desired output on your example.

Comment: I don't think the OP has asked for an XSLT solution. Also, you do not need _any_ of those for-each statements or variables.